# Macro breaks when run for the first time of the day when it adds another sheet to the file

Tags: excel, vba

When I run my macro for the first time for the day it fails when it adds another sheet to the file.

> Run-time error 1004: That name is already taken. Try a different
> one.

My goal:

1. look for the file within \Downloads
2. convert the saved file it found from .xls -> .xlsx
3. delete the original downloaded file
4. run a bunch of formatting for printing.

When it fails, I close the current file, re-download the file, manually save the file with the needed format & name, delete the download, re-download the file.
After that I can run the macro.

The line that breaks: `Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Dock Activity Report")).Name = "Cases"`

```vb
Sub Schedule_macro()

    Dim Filename, Pathname, SaveFileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim UserName As String

    UserName = Environ("username")
    Pathname = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Downloads\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "Dock_Activity_*.xls")
    SaveFileName = Dir(Pathname & "dockactivity.xlsx")
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Len(Dir(Pathname & "Dock_Activity_*.xls")) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Filename found, running macro"
    Else
        MsgBox "You need to download the" & vbNewLine & "Dock Activity Report from the" & vbNewLine & "'Report Run Log' in Lean." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Once downloaded, please rerun the macro", vbCritical, "HiRise Schedule Macro"
        Debug.Print "could not find Filename within given Pathname"
        Debug.Print "exiting macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
  
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        wb.CheckCompatibility = True
    
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.SaveAs Filename:="dockactivity", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
        Filename = Dir(Pathname & "Dock_Activity_*.xls")
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    If Dir(Pathname & "Dock_Activity_*.xls") <> "" Then
        kill (Pathname & "Dock_Activity_*.xls")
    End If

    Debug.Print "looking for SaveFileName within given Pathname"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & "dockactivity.xlsx")
    Debug.Print "SaveFileName found, opening file"

    Windows("dockactivity.xlsx").Activate
    Rows("1:21").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A:B,D:F,H:N,S:S,U:V,X:Y,AB:AK,AM:BA").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:H").Cut
    Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("K:K").Cut
    Columns("G:G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("J:K").Copy
    Range("L1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("J:K").ClearContents
    Range("J1").FormulaR1C1 = "Trailer Number"
    Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "Arrival Time"
    Columns("G:M").Copy
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("N1").FormulaR1C1 = "Door"
    Range("O1").FormulaR1C1 = "Ship Rail"
    Range("P1").FormulaR1C1 = "Staged"
    Range("Q1").FormulaR1C1 = "Check If Loaded"
    Range("R1").FormulaR1C1 = "Case Picks"
    Range("S1").FormulaR1C1 = "Layer Picks"
    Range("T1").FormulaR1C1 = "Check if Released by Pool"
    Debug.Print "1:1 table headers complete"
    Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 17.71
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 19.14
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 25.71
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 14.41
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 10.71
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 30.29
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 9.43
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 13.71
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 26.14
    Columns("K:L").ColumnWidth = 23.57
    Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 46
    Columns("N:S").ColumnWidth = 15
    Columns("T:T").ColumnWidth = 12.86
    Debug.Print "column resizing complete"
    Cells.Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 14
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 75
    Rows("2:150").RowHeight = 55
' #############################################################################    
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Dock Activity Report")).Name = "Cases"
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Cases")).Name = "Layers"
' #############################################################################    
    Sheets("Dock Activity Report").Range("R2:R150").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-17],Cases!C[-13]:C[-12],2,FALSE)"
    Sheets("Dock Activity Report").Range("S2:S150").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-18],Layers!C[-15]:C[-14],2,FALSE)"
    Worksheets("Dock Activity Report").Select
    Range("A2:T150").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$C2=""Live Trailer"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Range("B2:B150").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dock Activity Report").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dock Activity Report").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("B2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dock Activity Report").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:T150")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dock Activity Report").Select
    Columns("A:A").Copy
    Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-1]*1,TRIM(RC[-1]))"
    Range("B3").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B150"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B2:B150").Select
    Columns("B:B").Copy
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Debug.Print "A:A value reformat complete"
    Sheets("Dock Activity Report").Select
    Columns("A:T").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=COUNTA($A1:$F1)>0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Debug.Print "cell borders added"
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, 1) = 0 Then
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next r
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Sheets("Cases").Range("E2:E300").FormulaR1C1 = "=VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN(RC[-4])))"
    Sheets("Cases").Range("F2:F300").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]"
    Sheets("Cases").Columns("E:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Layers").Range("D2:D300").FormulaR1C1 = "=VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN(RC[-3])))"
    Sheets("Layers").Range("E2:E300").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]"
    Sheets("Layers").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Dock Activity Report").Range("A1").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "All Finished!", vbInformation, "HiRise Schedule"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is already a sheet with that name.

Add this code and it will be ok.

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Cases").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Dock Activity Report")).Name = "Cases"
```

**TIP**: Avoid the use of `.Select/Activate`. Work with Objects. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). It will be easy to manage the code as well.

Comment: Will I need to do this twice? Once for "Cases" and once for "Layers"?

Comment: Whenever you add a new sheet and name it, it is a good practice to check if that sheet exists **OR** simply delete it (whicever is convenient to you)

Comment: Why does the sheet still exist if I overwrite the save before it's opened?

Comment: Are you referring to `wb.SaveAs Filename:="dockactivity", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` ?

Comment: So open that file and check for hidden sheets. It is possible there is a hidden sheet with that name?

Comment: Not that I am able to find. The macro is ran daily but only fails when it is being ran for the first time of the day. After that, no issues

Comment: ok first things first. did you try as i suggested? using that code. did it work?

Comment: I added it, I won't be able to tell until tomorrow though since I've already ran this today.